Webpack error: TypeError: BundleDeclarationsWebpackPlugin is not a constructor
I am getting this error when merging typescript files using the Webpack BundleDeclarationsWebpackPlugin.
TypeError: BundleDeclarationsWebpackPlugin is not a constructor

What's wrong with my configuration below?
My Webpack config is:
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const BundleDeclarationsWebpackPlugin = require("bundle-declarations-webpack-plugin");


module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
   ...
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
      ...
  },
  plugins: [
    new BundleDeclarationsWebpackPlugin({
      entry: './dist/types/index.d.ts',    //specify the entry point for your declaration file (defaults to 'index.d.ts')
      outFile: './dist/index.d.ts',        //specify the output file name (defaults to 'index.d.ts')
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
  }
};


